# How much control do we have over the local characters of an idele class character?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, and $v_0$ a finite place of $K$.  Let $\eta$ be a quasicharacter of $K_{v_0}^{\ast}$.  Does there exist a character $\chi = \otimes \chi_v$ of the idele class group $\mathbb I_K/K^{\ast}$ such that $\chi_{v_0} = \chi$, and $\chi_v$ is unramified for all finite $v \neq v_0$?

Similarly, if $v_1, ... , v_n$ are places of $K$, is it possible to have an idele class character having specified restrictions to each $K_{v_i}^{\ast}$?  What is the best way to think about characters of $\mathbb I_K/K^{\ast}$ to answer questions like these?

Answer (score 3):

This question, which I only found recently, has some overlap with the phenomenon described in the MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310315/inclusion-of-multiplicative-group-of-one-local-field-into-the-idele-class-group) that was asked at around the same time as this question.

I'll show how to settle the existence question for a single quasi-character $\eta$ of $K_{v_0}^\times$: find a quasi-character $\chi$ of $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ with $v_0$-component $\eta$ that is unramified at all other finite places of $K$. In fact, $v_0$ can be an arbitrary place of $K$, including an archimedean one, and $\chi$ can be chosen to be unramified at all places of $K$ other than $v_0$.

Let $v_0$ be a place of $K$ (finite or infinite) and $\eta$ be a quasi-character of $K_{v_0}^\times$. I want to reduce to the setting of characters. There is $\sigma \in \mathbf R$ such that $|\eta(x)| = |x|_{v_0}^\sigma$ for all $x$ in $K_{v_0}^\times$.  This means $\eta'(x) := \eta(x)|x|_{v_0}^{-\sigma}$ defines a *character* ($S^1$-valued) of $K_{v_0}^\times$. If we can find a character $\chi'$ of $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ that has $v_0$-component $\eta'$ then $\chi(\mathbf x) := \chi'(\mathbf x)|\!|\mathbf x|\!|^\sigma$ (here and below I write $|\!|\mathbf x|\!|$ for the idelic norm on $\mathbb I_K$) is a quasi-character of $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ that has $v_0$-component $\eta$: for $x \in K_{v_0}^\times$  placed in the $v_0$-component of $\mathbb I_K$ in the calculation below, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\chi(1,\ldots,1,x,1,\ldots) & = & \chi'(1,\ldots,1,x,1,\ldots)|\!|(1,\ldots,1,x,1,\ldots)|\!|^\sigma \\
& = & \chi'(1,\ldots,1,x,1,\ldots)|x|_{v_0}^\sigma \\
&  = & \eta'(x)|x|_{v_0}^\sigma  \\
& = & \eta(x).
\end{eqnarray*}
Thus $\eta$ is the $v_0$-component of $\chi$. Furthermore, $\chi$ is unramified at exactly the places where $\chi'$ is unramified: for a place $v \not= v_0$ of $K$ and $y \in K_{v}^\times$ with $|y|_v = 1$ that 
is placed into $\mathbb I_K$ in the $v$-component, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\chi(1,\ldots,1,y,1,\ldots) & = & \chi'(1,\ldots,1,y,1,\ldots)|\!|(1,\ldots,1,y,1,\ldots)|\!|^\sigma \\
& = & \chi'(1,\ldots,1,y,1,\ldots)|y|_{v}^\sigma \\
& = & \chi'(1,\ldots,1,y,1,\ldots),
\end{eqnarray*}
so for each place $v \not= v_0$ of $K$ the $v$-components of 
$\chi$ and $\chi'$ are equal on $\{y \in K_v^\times : |y|_v = 1\}$.

Our goal now is to show each character $\eta'$ of $K_{v_0}^\times$ is the $v_0$-component of some character $\chi'$ of $\mathbb I_K$ and make $\chi$' unramified at all places of $K$ other than $v_0$.

The composite group homomorphism 
$K_{v_0}^\times \rightarrow \mathbb I_K \rightarrow \mathbb I_K/K^\times$ is continuous and injective. This embedding is closed and the quotient $(\mathbb I_K/K^\times)/K_{v_0}^\times$ is compact; see
the MO page [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310315/inclusion-of-multiplicative-group-of-one-local-field-into-the-idele-class-group) (the question, answers, and comments) for a discussion of these properties.  Inside $\mathbb I_K$ let 
$$
U_{v_0}' = \prod_{v \not= v_0} \{y \in K_v^\times : |y|_v = 1\} \times \{1\},
$$ 
where the $\{1\}$ at the end is the $v_0$ component.  The continuous group homomorphism $\mathbb I_K \rightarrow \mathbb I_K/K^\times$ is an embedding on  $U_{v_0}'$, and since $U_{v_0}'$ is compact its image in $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ is compact.  From this we will show the image of 
$$
U_{v_0}K_{v_0}^\times = \prod_{v \not= v_0} \{y \in K_v^\times : |y|_v = 1\} \times K_{v_0}^\times = U_{v_0}' \times K_{v_0}^\times 
$$
in $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ is closed.

When $G$ is an abelian topological group with closed subgroups $C$ and $H$ such that $C$ is compact and $G/H$ is compact, the subgroup $CH = \{hc : h \in H, c \in C\}$ in $G$ is closed: the continuous mapping $G \rightarrow G/H$ sends $C$ onto $CH/H$, so $CH/H$ is closed and thus its inverse image $CH$ in $G$ is closed.
Apply this with $G = \mathbb I_K/K^\times$, $C = U_{v_0}'$ (as an embedded subgroup of $G$), and $H = K_{v_0}^\times$ (as an embedded subgroup of $G$) to see that 
the image of $U_{v_0}' \times K_{v_0}^\times$ under $\mathbb I_K \rightarrow \mathbb I_K/K^\times$ is closed.

The character $\eta'$ on $K_{v_0}^\times$ extends to a character of 
$U_{v_0}' \times K_{v_0}^\times$ by declaring it to be trivial on $U_{v_0}'$. That is, use the composite $U_{v_0}' \times K_{v_0}^\times \rightarrow K_{v_0}^\times \rightarrow S^1$ where the second function is $\eta'$. Now view 
$U_{v_0}' \times K_{v_0}^\times$ as an embedded closed subgroup of $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ by the process described above. (The groups $K_{v_0}^\times$ and $U_{v_0}'$ intersect trivially in $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ since no element of $K^\times$ is in $U_{v_0}'$ inside $\mathbb I_K$ other than $1$.) From Pontryagin duality (for *characters*, not quasi-characters!) every character of a closed subgroup of a locally compact abelian group can be lifted to a character of the whole group.  Therefore the character we gave on $U_{v_0}' \times K_{v_0}^\times$ that is trivial on $U_{v_0}'$ and is $\eta'$ on $K_{v_0}^\times$ can be lifted to a character of $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ (in *many* ways). Let $\chi'$ be any such lifting.  Then $\chi'$ is a character of $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ that 
equals $\eta'$ on the embedded copy of $K_{v_0}^\times$ and is trivial on the embedded copy of $U_{v_0}'$.  This means, in terms of local components of a character on $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$, that the $v_0$-component of $\chi'$ is $\eta'$ 
and, for each place $v$ of $K$ other than $v_0$, the $v$-component of $\chi'$ is trivial on $\{y \in K_v^\times : |y|_v = 1\}$, so $\chi'$ is unramified at all places of $K$ other than $v_0$, finite or infinite, and therefore the quasi-character $\chi$ constructed above that has $v_0$-component $\eta$ is unramified at every place of $K$ other than $v_0$.

Note:  If $\eta$ is a finite-order character of $K_{v_0}^\times$ then we may ask for $\chi$ to be a finite-order character of $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ with the same order as $\eta$ and ramification related to that of $\eta$. This can be achieved except in some rare situations described by the Grunwald-Wang theorem; see the paper by Song Wang (not the "Wang" from Grunwald-Wang) on the arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0389.pdf), especially paragraph 4 of Section 1 and Theorem 2.2.

For $n$ quasi-characters $\eta_1, \ldots \eta_n$ of $K_{v_1}^\times, \ldots, K_{v_n}^\times$ with $n > 1$, to have a quasi-charater $\chi$ on $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ with $v_i$-component $\eta_i$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ definitely imposes a restriction: the exponents of all the $\eta_i$ must be the same. That is, there has to be a $\sigma \in \mathbf R$ such that for $i = 1, \ldots, n$ we have $|\eta_i(x)| = |x|_{v_i}^\sigma$ for all $x \in K_{v_i}^\times$ because the exponent of a quasi-character on $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ equals the exponent of each of its local components. Using a common exponent $\sigma$ for the $\eta_i$, the $\sigma$-power of the absolute value on each $K_{v_i}$ and the $\sigma$-power of the idelic norm on $\mathbb I_K$ can be used to show the existence question is equivalent to the case of characters (when $\sigma = 0$).

The necessary condition that all $\eta_i$ have the same exponent is not sufficient, and I will explain how to give counterexamples in the case $K = \mathbf Q$. 
For a character $\chi$ of $\mathbb I_\mathbf Q$ (don't assume yet that $\chi$ is trivial on $\mathbf Q^\times$), let $\chi_v \colon \mathbf Q_v^\times \hookrightarrow \mathbb I_\mathbf Q \rightarrow S^1$ be its $v$-component, so 
by continuity of  $\chi$ all but finitely many $\chi_p$ are trivial on $\mathbf Z_p^\times$. 
For all $\mathbf x \in \mathbb I_\mathbf Q$, with $v$-component $x_v$, we have 
$\chi(\mathbf x) = \prod_v \chi_v(x_v)$.

We will show that having $\chi$ be trivial on $\mathbf Q^\times$ imposes a constraint on its components $\chi_v$ that we can use to give an example, for each pair of places $v$ and $w$ of $\mathbf Q$, 
of characters $\eta_v$ of $\mathbf Q_v^\times$ and $\eta_w$ of $\mathbf Q_w^\times$ that 
are not the components of a character of $\mathbb I_\mathbf Q/\mathbf Q^\times$.  The idea that 
this should be possible (for a general number field, but I stick to $\mathbf Q$ for concreteness) 
comes from the main question on the MO post [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310315/inclusion-of-multiplicative-group-of-one-local-field-into-the-idele-class-group), which concerns 
the composite map $K_v^\times \times K_w^\times \hookrightarrow \mathbb I_K \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb I_K/K^\times$ not having a closed image 
for many choices of $v$ and $w$ (e.g., when $v$ and $w$ are non-archimedean not lying over the same prime of $\mathbf Q$). 
If the image were closed then my argument above showing that a single local character of $K_{v_0}^\times$ 
is the $v_0$-component of a character of $\mathbb I_K/K^\times$ could be adapted to a pair of characters
of $K_{v_0}^\times$ and $K_{w_0}^\times$.

The characters of $\mathbf Q_v^\times$ have standard formulas.  For $v = \infty$, 
we can write for $x \in \mathbf R^\times$ 
$$
\chi_\infty(x) = ({\rm sgn } \, x)^\delta|x|^{ic_\infty},
$$
where $\delta$ is 0 or 1  and $c_\infty \in \mathbf R$.  The number ${\rm sgn} \, x$ is $\pm 1$.
For $v = p$ we can write for $x \in \mathbf Q_p^\times$ 
$$
 \chi_p(x) = \chi_p(u_x)|x|_p^{ic_p}
$$
where  $u_x = x/p^{{\rm ord}_p(x)}$ is the unit part of a nonzero $p$-adic number $x$ (we use on $\mathbf Q_p^\times$ the standard uniformizer $p$) and $c_p \in \mathbf R$.  The number $\chi_p(u_x)$ 
is a root of unity (of order dividing some $p^k(p-1)$).  We'll use these formulas in the following claim.

Claim: If a character $\chi$ of $\mathbb I_\mathbf Q$ 
is trivial on $\mathbf Q^\times$ then for each prime $p$, $c_p - c_\infty \in (\pi/\log p)\mathbf Q$.

Proof:  We have $1 = \chi(p,p,p,\ldots) = \chi_\infty(p)\chi_p(p)\prod_{v \not= p,\infty} \chi_v(p)$.  From the formulas for each $\chi_v$, 
for $v$ not $p$ or $\infty$ the number $\chi_v(p)$ is a root of unity (and most $\chi_v(p) = 1$), so 
$\chi_\infty(p)\chi_p(p)$ is a root of unity.  Feeding into this condition 
the formulas for $\chi_\infty(p)$ and $\chi_p(p)$, we see that $p^{ic_\infty} (1/p)^{ic_p}$ is a root of unity. 
Thus $p^{i(c_\infty - c_p)} = 1$, so $(c_\infty - c_p)(\log p)/(2\pi) \in \mathbf Q$, and that completes the proof of the claim.

Example 1: There are characters of $\mathbf R^\times$ and $\mathbf Q_p^\times$ 
that are not components of a character of $\mathbb I_\mathbf Q/\mathbf Q^\times$.

Pick a real number $c_\infty$.  The set $c_\infty + (\pi/\log p)\mathbf Q$ is countable, so 
there is a real number $c_p$ not lying in $c_\infty + (\pi/\log p)\mathbf Q$. By the claim, the characters
$\chi_\infty(x) = ({\rm sgn} \, x)^\delta|x|^{ic_\infty}$ (for $\delta = 0$ or $1$) 
and $\chi_p(x) = \varepsilon_p(u_x)|x|_p^{ic_p}$ (for any continuous character $\varepsilon_p$ of $\mathbf Z_p^\times$) are not the archimedean and $p$-adic components of a character of $\mathbb I_\mathbf Q/\mathbf Q^\times$.

Note: The number $\pi/\log p$ is almost certainly transcendental, but I believe even a proof of its irrationality is still an open question for 
every prime $p$.  If we accept that $\pi/\log p$ is transcendental or just irrational then we can use 
for $c_\infty$ and $c_p$ in Example 1 two different integers.

Example 2: For primes $p$ and $q$, there are characters of $\mathbf Q_p^\times$ and $\mathbf Q_q^\times$ 
that are not components of a character of $\mathbb I_\mathbf Q/\mathbf Q^\times$.

For each character $\chi$ of $\mathbb I_\mathbf Q/\mathbf Q^\times$
we have $c_p - c_\infty \in (\pi/\log p)\mathbf Q$ and $c_q - c_\infty \in (\pi/\log q)\mathbf Q$ by the claim above, so 
$$
c_\infty \in \left(c_p + \frac{\pi}{\log p}\mathbf Q\right) \cap \left(c_q + \frac{\pi}{\log q}\mathbf Q\right).
$$
If we pick $c_p$ and $c_q$ in $\mathbf R$ to make the above intersection empty then 
there is no choice for $c_\infty$, so a character $\chi_p(x) = \varepsilon_p(u_x)|x|_p^{ic_p}$ 
on $\mathbf Q_p^\times$ and $\chi_q(x) = \varepsilon_q(u_x)|x|_p^{ic_q}$ on $\mathbf Q_q^\times$ 
using the exponents $c_p$ and $c_q$ (and arbitrary characters $\varepsilon_p$ on $\mathbf Z_p^\times$ 
and $\varepsilon_q$ on $\mathbf Z_q^\times$) are not components of a character of $\mathbb I_\mathbf Q/\mathbf Q^\times$.

Pick $c_p \in \mathbf R$.  The set $c_p + (\pi/\log p)\mathbf Q + (\pi/\log q)\mathbf Q$ is countable, so 
there is a real number $c_q$ not belonging to that set, and with that choice of 
$c_q$ the sets $c_p + (\pi/\log p)\mathbf Q$ and $c_q + (\pi/\log q)\mathbf Q$ are disjoint.

Probably a concrete choice is $c_p = 0$ and $c_q = \pi$, or more generally $c_p$ and $c_q$ are two different rational multiples of $\pi$, since 
$\{1, 1/\log p, 1/\log q\}$ is almost certainly a linearly independent set over $\mathbf Q$, but I believe 
this is still an open problem.  If there were a linear dependence relation, the coefficient of $1$ would have 
to be nonzero since $1/\log p$ and $1/\log q$ are linearly independent over $\mathbf Q$, so we'd have 
$p^{\log q}$ equal to $p^rq^s$ for some rational $r$ and $s$, making $p^{\log q}$ algebraic, but almost 
certainly $p^{\log q}$ is transcendental and I think this transcendence is still an open question.

Comment: I had convinced myself that an idele class character cannot be a prescribed ramified character at exactly one place and be unramified everywhere else. The basic example I had in mind, for $\mathbb{Q}$, was: 'if I try to set $\chi_{\infty}(-1) = -1$ and $\chi_p$ unramified everywhere else, I get $\chi(-1) = -1$, a contradiction'. But this answer seems to suggest it can be done. Am I making a mistake in my counterexample?